# How to make AOSP build VNDK compliant?

Tags: android, android-source

I have enabled the flag **BOARD_VNDK_VERSION := current**. During compilation., i got error like: **LOCAL_USE_VNDK and LOCAL_COPY_HEADERS**. I studied **platform/development/vndk/tools/vndk-compliance/README.md** file, in that file it says that **Vendor modules are not allowed to use LOCAL_COPY_HEADERS**, iam trying to change those copy headers but i can't able to do it. Please give me clear clarification on changing those headers.